# Paste 2 strings in R with \"

Tags: r, special-characters, paste

I have 2 strings in R

```
a = "Argyle Extension Tube 20\""
b = "MISC"
```

When I am pasting in R,

```
paste(a,b)
"Argyle Extension Tube 20\" MISC"
```

I want to have:

```
"Argyle Extension Tube 20 MISC"
```

How can I do this? The original strings are derived from external source. I am just using these as an example.

Answer (score 1):

We remove the '"' with `gsub` (if there is only one instance, use `sub`) and do the paste

```
paste(gsub('"', '', a), b)
#[1] "Argyle Extension Tube 20 MISC"
```

Comment: Thank you. @akrun This is helpful